# how to add button cell.contentview not working perfect?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have created one application in which if i select on particular row in Table View than that selected row will expand(I have implemented row onclick row expand perfectly but i have problem with [cell.contentview addsubview:] please see image i have provided) & there is some button but i can't get perfect view in table view without clicking row i can see other cell's button [here is image!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/70v8n.png)

my code for displaying button is here.

```
    -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

        cell = [tableBusiness dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {

            //cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        }
        //cell.textLabel.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleNone;
        cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row];

        UILabel *theText = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0,10.0, 200, 22.0)];
        theText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"  Title Text %d",indexPath.row];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:theText];

        btnMenu = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        btnMenu.frame = CGRectMake(80, 160, 100, 37);
        [btnMenu setTitle:@"Go to Menu" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btnMenu addTarget:nil action:@selector(accessoryTypeForRowWithIndexPath:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:btnMenu];
        //textView.text = nil;    

        return cell;
        [btnMenu release];

        [theText release];

}
```

& i want to make button events like on clicking particular button open that clicked button product how to do that? 
does any have solutions please help me.
[i want to create like this !](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UD8gL.jpg)[Here is description for the image thread.](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/50564-accordion-table-cell-how-dynamically-expand-contract-uitableviewcell.html)

[here its link for how to expand row.?](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/25811-uitableview-expand-effect.html)

Comment: This is really disgusting... if anybody can't give answer than tell me why you have down-vote my question. you have read my question perfectly.? have anybody seen all given useful data provided by me to explain you?? Can anybody tell me whats wrong here????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to increase the height of cell then u can try with following code

```
UITableView *movieListTbl;
movieListTbl.rowHeight = "Height of cell";
```

But remember that you delegate your tableview.

Comment: i think you didn't get my point. please read my question i have implemented that row increase but i want to know my answer for cell.content view pls see image i have provided. iN this tag here is image!